# Allure empty report being generated using Karma

Tags: allure

I'm using the following [plugin](https://github.com/allure-framework/karma-allure-reporter)

However after generating the report, which is the following ,please note that it was a test test (pun non intended)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:test-suite xmlns:ns2="urn:model.allure.qatools.yandex.ru" start="1413502062818" stop="1413502063182">
    <title>Car</title>
    <test-cases start="1413502062834" stop="1413502062840" status="passed">
        <title>should return null</title>
        <description>Something</description>
        <steps start="1413502062817" stop="1413502062817" status="passed">
            <title>Create an empty car and return it</title>
        </steps>
        <steps start="1413502062828" stop="1413502062828" status="passed">
            <title>Create an empty car and return it</title>
        </steps>
    </test-cases>
    <test-cases start="1413502062867" stop="1413502062880" status="passed">
        <title>should return null</title>
        <description>Something</description>
        <steps start="1413502062867" stop="1413502062867" status="passed">
            <title>Create an empty car and return it</title>
        </steps>
    </test-cases>
    <test-cases start="1413502062818" stop="1413502063182" status="passed">
        <title>should return null</title>
    </test-cases>
</ns2:test-suite>
```

And using `allure generate ""` in the location of the xml file, the following is generated.

[image]

Any kind of help is highly appreciated, **thank you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Karma adapter only supports Allure 1.3.x series. You could try to generate the same report like that:

```
$ allure generate -v 1.3.9 path/to/directory/with/xml
```

There's an [issue](https://github.com/allure-framework/karma-allure-reporter/issues/2) about updating Karma adapter to 1.4.x but in fact nobody of the team works on that because of low demand and because we are not using Karma at all. So the fastest way to be able to use Allure 1.4.0 with Karma adapter is to send a PR that we will review and merge. If you're really interested in using Allure with Karma - you could even become an official supporter of this adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select filters (Failed,..., Passed) on UI. On your screenshot no filters are selected.

(I have come to the same empty report once and was really confused)

Comment: You should select Passed. Make it Grey.

Comment: I tried it already. I'm telling you, it's not something like that what's happening.

Comment: Then I take my solution back. (To further investigate issue you can look through generated json at report data folder)